# Finding a basis for a solution of system of Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system of differential equation

$x'(t) =  Ax(t)$. where

$A  = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0\\
 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

I need to find the basis for this system of differential equation.

Now, I take

$x(t) = (x_1(t), x_2(t))^{T}$

This gives the system of equation as:

$\begin{pmatrix}
 x_1'(t)\\
x_2'(t)
\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
 x_1(t)\\
2x_1(t) + x_2(t)
\end{pmatrix}$

Solving this system gives me :  $x_1(t) = c_1e^t$

$x_2(t) = 2c_1te^t + c_2e^t$

So, the solution is given by :
$X(t) =$

$\begin{pmatrix}
c_1e^t\\
2c_1te^t + c_2e^t
\end{pmatrix}$

Clearly this solution is $X(t)$ is spanned by  : $\begin{pmatrix}
e^t\\
2te^t
\end{pmatrix}$  and $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
e^t
\end{pmatrix}$

As, the given solution is linearly independent and spans given solution space , this forms the basis of $x(t)$

Is my solution correct?

Please tell if there is any inaccuracy in the solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Why don't you compute the derivatives of your solutions and test if those are indeed satisfying the initial differential equation? A good way in general to validate your own result!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net So, if I resubstitute the solutions, I find that it does satisfy the original equation, however my query is: Is my method to compute basis of this system correct?

Comment: Your solution is correct. In the answer below, I made some minor comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct. Some minor elements to improve it:

- You can change the sentence *Clearly this solution is $X(t)$ is spanned by...* by *the linear subspace of the solutions is spaned by...*.
- You could explain how you got $x_2$ solution.